# why isn't the mobius band an algebraic line bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, intuition

When I hear the phrase "line bundle" the first thing that pops into my head is a mobius band. But this is a bad picture from an algebraic point of view since any line bundle on an affine variety is trivial. Anyway, my question is: is there a way of seeing more concretely what "goes wrong" when you try to construct the mobius band as an algebraic line bundle over ℝ, and what changes when you move to analytic line bundles?

Comment: I can't find your email address. Drop me a line: langer.robin@gmail.com In actual answer to your question - something about a non-vanishing chern class. Look in Manivel's book. Its a great book. Do you have a copy?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider the real algebraic line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ over the real algebraic variety $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$. It is nontrivial hence continuously isomorphic to the "Moebius" line bundle (there are only 2 line bundles on the circle, up to continuous isomorphism), so its total space is homeomorphic o the "Moebius strip".

By the way, it is false that line bundles on affine algebraic varieties are trivial. One example is the above universal line bundle over $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$. If you want an example over $\mathbb{C}$, consider the complement of a point in an elliptic curve: it's an affine variety but its Picard group is far from being trivial.

Comment: thanks for that, the thing about line bundles being trivial was told to me today by a topology professor, i guess she was confused.

Comment: Your comment about $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^1$ is correct, but may be confusing to some.  One of the interesting features of real algebraic geometry is that $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^n$ is (also) the real analytic manifold associated to a smooth **affine** variety.  So there is, in this sense, no distinction between affine and projective varieties over $\mathbb{R}$.  

Comment: Affine algebraic varieties behave trivially w.r.t. cohomology of coherent sheaves, but their geometry can still be nontrivial (even from the purely topological viewpoint).

Comment: @maxmoo: There is a related true result here: a coherent sheaf on an affine variety $X$ is acyclic for sheaf cohomology: its higher cohomology groups are all zero.  One might be tempted to deduce from this that $\operatorname{Pic}(X) = H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}) = 0$.  But this is not valid: $\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}$ is not a coherent sheaf.  

Comment: ah that explains it

Comment: @Pete: yes, O^* is not a coherent sheaf simply because it is *not* a sheaf of O_X-modules, but just a sheaf of abelian groups.

Comment: The professor may have been talking about the analytic category. What's true is that affine varieties over $C$ are Stein manifolds, so that coherent analytic sheaf cohomology vanishes as well. Then the exponential sequence for $O_X$ implies that an analytic line bundle is determined by its topological first Chern class. In the case of an affine algebraic curve, for example, this implies analytic triviality.

Comment: Just to expand a little on Pete's point: $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is isomorphic to $x^2+y^2=1$. Over the complex numbers, the former is a sphere and the latter is a sphere with two punctures, but the punctures are complex conjugates of each other, so you don't see them in the real picture. I think you should be able to write the Mobius band explicitly as `$\{(x,y,u,v) : \ x^2+y^2=1 \ (u^2-v^2)y=2uv x \}$`. In other words, it is the set of pairs of complex numbers $(z,w)$ such that $z$ has norm $1$ and $\mathrm{arg}(z)=2 \mathrm{arg}(w)$.

Comment: @MinhyongKim: what do you mean by "this" in "this implies analytic triviality"? You mean that on an affine algebraic variety (e.g. an affine curve) having trivial (topological) first Chern class implies being holomorphically trivial, right? 

Comment: Yes, an affine algebraic curve has trivial topological $H^2$, so all line bundles are topologically trivial. But then, they are also Stein spaces, so this implies that line bundles are analytically trivial.

Comment: @MinhyongKim: I'm getting very confused, as your comment seems (superficially) to contradict my example with the elliptic curve minus one point. My goal in that example was to provide an example of an affine alg curve with *algebraically* nontrivial line bundles on it. (to be continued)    

Comment: (continued) So, take $X$  an elliptic curve; then $X−p$  is an affine smooth algebraic curve ($p$  is any closed point of $X$ ). Now, applying Proposition 6.5 and Corollary 6.15 from Hartshorne to the present case, we have the exact sequence: $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow Pic(X) \rightarrow Pic(X-p) \rightarrow 0$ (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) If every line bundle on $X-p$ was algebraically trivial, that is, if $Pic(X-p)=0$, then $Pic(X)$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which is well known not to be the case. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) On the other hand, workin analytically, we can write down the exponential sequence and, taking into account that $X-p$ is affine hence Stein, we have that the first Chern class is an isomorphism $H^1(X^{an}, \mathcal{O}_X^{an, \times})\rightarrow H^2(X^{an}, \mathbb{Z})$. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) MinhyongKim: could you please elaborate a bit why every affine curve would have trivial "topological $H^2$" (I suppose you mean the $H^2(X^{an},\mathbb{Z})$, right?)... Anyway, given this fact and the above isomorphism, one would conclude that the *analytic* Picard group of $X-p$ would be trivial. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) Thus, if what I've written makes sense, we have shown an easy example in which there are algebraically nontrivial line bundles that are analytically trivial. So the possibility of using holomorphic functions instead of only algebraic would give more "degrees of freedom" to trivialize an alg. nontrivial bundle. Are there any mistakes in my reasoning? thank you.

Comment: Misprint: in the above comments, of course, I actually meant $H^1(X^{an}-p,\mathcal{O}_{X-p}^{an, \times})\rightarrow H^2(X^{an}-p,\mathbb{Z})$ is an $\cong$.

Comment: P.S.: ah, I see now why top. H^2 is trivial: a noncompact differentiable $n-$manifold doesn't have a fundamental class.

Comment: All that you write is correct. To be frank, the analytic triviality has always seemed a bit mysterious to me as well. Regarding the triviality of $H^2$, I guess the easiest way to see this is to note that a compact Riemann surface minus some points is homotopic to a graph.